# sufficient and necessary condition to change the order of minimization (infimum)

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

We want to know the sufficient and necessary condition of $\inf_{F\in set A}\inf_{0\leq p\leq 1}g(F,p)=\inf_{0\leq p\leq 1}\inf_{F\in set A}g(F,p)$, where $F$ is a function and set $A$ is a set of functionals. One potential answer is that set $A$ is compact and $g(F,p)$ is lower semi-continuous for both $F$ and $p$. But I don't know how to prove it. Or is there any references?

Comment: This is true without any assumption whatsoever. If $X$ and $Y$ are any sets and $g:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ any function, then $\inf_X\inf_Y g(x,y)=\inf_{X\times Y} g(x,y)=\inf_Y\inf_X 
 g(x,y)$

Comment: Thank you so much!